# Image is not uploading from application

Tags: java, android

I have an application in which i upload 4 images to my server when the size of the image is below 20kb then it successfully uploaded otherwise it does not.
Here is my code

```
     public void ImageUploadToServerFunction() {

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStreamObject1,byteArrayOutputStreamObject2,byteArrayOutputStreamObject3,byteArrayOutputStreamObject4;

            byteArrayOutputStreamObject1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byteArrayOutputStreamObject2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byteArrayOutputStreamObject3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byteArrayOutputStreamObject4 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, byteArrayOutputStreamObject1);
            bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, byteArrayOutputStreamObject2);
            bitmap3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, byteArrayOutputStreamObject3);
            bitmap4.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, byteArrayOutputStreamObject4);

            byte[] byteArrayVar1 = byteArrayOutputStreamObject1.toByteArray();

            ConvertImage1  = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar1, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] byteArrayVar2 = byteArrayOutputStreamObject2.toByteArray();

            ConvertImage2  = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar2, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] byteArrayVar3 = byteArrayOutputStreamObject3.toByteArray();

            ConvertImage3  = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar3, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] byteArrayVar4 = byteArrayOutputStreamObject4.toByteArray();

            ConvertImage4  = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar4, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: You should use multipart to upload images.

Answer (score 0):

add this library:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
```

And put this code to upload image to server.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        final JSONObject jsonObject = uploadImage(strImagePath);
                        if (jsonObject != null) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    Log.d(TAG, "Response : " + jsonObject.toString());

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

public JSONObject uploadImage(String profileFileUri) {
        try {
            final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");
            RequestBody r = null;
            RequestBody k = null;
            String extension = null;
            String ext = null;

            String userID = "1";

            if (profileFileUri != null) {
                File sourceFile = new File(profileFileUri);

                Log.d(TAG, "File...::::" + sourceFile + " : " + sourceFile.exists());

                final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPG = MediaType.parse("image/jpg");
                final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
                final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_GIF = MediaType.parse("image/gif");

                if (profileFileUri.contains(".jpg")) {
                    k = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, sourceFile);
                    ext = ".jpg";
                } else if (profileFileUri.contains(".jpeg")) {
                    ext = ".jpeg";
                    k = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG, sourceFile);
                } else if (profileFileUri.contains(".png")) {
                    ext = ".png";
                    k = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile);
                } else if (profileFileUri.contains(".gif")) {
                    ext = ".gif";
                    k = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_GIF, sourceFile);
                }
            }
            ArrayList<String> imgList = new ArrayList<>();
            MultipartBody requestBody;

            MultipartBody.Builder mRequestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
            mRequestBody.addFormDataPart("Test", Consts.token_auth);
            mRequestBody.addFormDataPart("proccess_id", "1");
            mRequestBody.addFormDataPart("img1", "IMG" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ext, k);
            mRequestBody.addFormDataPart("img2", "IMG" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ext, k);
            mRequestBody.addFormDataPart("img3", "IMG" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ext, k);
            mRequestBody.addFormDataPart("img4", "IMG" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ext, k);
            mRequestBody.addFormDataPart("img5", "IMG" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ext, k);
            mRequestBody.addFormDataPart("if_shop_act", "yes");

            for (MediaPojo pojo : aryMedialist) {

                mRequestBody.addFormDataPart("shop_act[]", pojo.getName().replace(" ", "_") + ".png", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File(pojo.getPath())));
                imgList.add(pojo.getName());

                Log.v("ImageData", pojo.getName() + " - " + pojo.getPath());

            }


            RequestBody rb = mRequestBody.build();

            Log.v("Test", android.text.TextUtils.join("|", imgList));

            Log.d(TAG, "uploadImage param  : " + rb.toString());
            okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                    .url("Your URL")
                    .post(rb)
                    .build();


            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            String res = response.body().string();

            Log.d(TAG, "Response : " + res);
            return new JSONObject(res);

        } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {


            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {


            Log.e(TAG, "Other Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

i hope its helpful to you ...!

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload image using asynctask task with single image including all failed possibility & also try check the image size/quality. Android behaviors out of memory exception as per device ram capacity.